# HWIOAuthBundle without login

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

I need this logic:

1. user login with FOS user bundle
2. user click on google logo (for example) and login with google+
3. googleId token is saved in User entity.

So there is no firewall with HWIOAuthBundle and I need to use only HWIOAuthBundle listener. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.
v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for HWIOAuth Connect functionality so you can connect a social media account (Google) to an existing FOS user.This may help you:

https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/hwioauth-registration-form/